# Is this logo copyright infringment of Beats' logo?

Tags: logo, copyright, legal

I was recently informed by friends that my logo looks far too much like Beats' logo, and I did find it to be so.

I made some adjustments, but it in my mind, it still looks fairly similar. Yet, there is almost no identical elements, except for the **p** standing for "Plenty" -- our project's name. (which is a **b** in the beats logo).

Here are the two side by side. Do you think I'm infringing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your best bet: ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is that similar to **Beats** logo, it is however, a bit similar to **Publix** logo:

[image]

Especially because of the colors

---

On another note, that curve under the **p** doesn't seem to fit.It doesn't look like a natural curve (notice how it *indents* and then curves).

In the Publix and Beats logo, they don't even have a curve at all.

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for bringing the Publix logo up! And the curve, though what do you mean by "fit" exactly?

Comment: @Andrey updated.